# Custom Button not evaluating Enable Rules in Advanced Find ribbon

Tags: dynamics-crm, ribbon, crm-ribbon-workbench

do you know whether the enable rules of buttons created in Ribbon Workbench are deprecated in Advanced Find?

Hi, I have two buttons enabled in the subgrid, which appear on advanced find. I noticed that enable rules are completely ignored in AF, both with "System" or "Custom" rules, and the [buttons results are disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haKed.png). On UCI, they show up [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7wVd.png)

Any feedback on that?